# Converting a dictionary to unicode object

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, wtforms

i am using WTForms and there is an example that does this following where Properties is a model defined in the model.py class:

```
formProp_cls = model_form(Properties)
formProp = formProp_cls(obj=xyz)
```

Can anyone tell me what type of parameters does the formProp_cls take because this is suppose to repopulate the field in the form i think but i dont know the format of the object.

Many thanks

Comment: Would you please post a link to the example?

Answer (score 0):

By default the `model_form` call returns a subclass of `wtforms.form.Form`. If you are using Flask it is a good idea to request a subclass of `flask.ext.wtf.Form` instead, by adding this class as a second argument:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
formProp_cls = model_form(Properties, Form)
```

You typically initialize this form by passing the `request.form` in the constructor:

```
formProp = formProp_cls(request.form)
```